# Watson LT SDK create_model() fails if forced_glossary is in /tmp/ folder

Tags: python-3.x, ibm-watson

The Watson LT create_model() fails if the glossary file is in a folder outside the local dir.   Kinda crazy... why would location of TMX file matter?

It works if I just the basename (CustomModel_xxxx.tmx) w/o a folder.

If fails with error below if I use /tmp/CustomModel_xxxx.tmx

I don't want tmx files created in my code base...

Running on Py 3.5. in a jupyter notebook

WatsonApiException: Error: Error while uploading file(s). Please try again!, Code: 500 , X-dp-watson-tran-id: gateway02-898567107 , X-global-transaction-id: ffea405d5bfc5adf358f0bc3

CODE:

```
    from watson_developer_cloud import LanguageTranslatorV3
    lt = LanguageTranslatorV3(....)

    DIR = kwargs.get('folder','/tmp')
    bn = 'CustomModel_%d.tmx' % os.getpid()

    # Fails
    tmx_name = os.path.join(DIR, bn)
    # Is ok
    #tmx_name = bn

   with open(tmx_FN,'r', encoding='U8') as fio:
        x = fio.read()
        print("Read ok",)

        r = lt.create_model(
            base_model_id=model_id,
            name = 'xxx',
            **{'forced_glossary': fio}
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example with Python 2.7 and it works fine on my system. My best guess is that you have some kind of permissions problem with `/tmp` on your system.  Or maybe jupyter is remapping /tmp somehow. What happens if you run this as a standalone python app?